# Select rows that don't exist in other table join by data in the second table [SQL]

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, stored-procedures

First there is the table that holds the dates and whether or not it was a holiday. This table holds all the dates from the beginning of time to the end of time :)

```
Table Calendar
-DMY date PK
-isHoliday bit
```

Secondly the Attendance table holds the the attendance of people. If a person is onleave then the flag is set to 1.

```
Table Attendance
-Id int PK
-DMY date FK
-CheckIn time
-PersonId int
-onLeave bit
```

Now I would like to get a view that tells me the people who were absent or on leave in a given interval. The problem is, there is no entry in Attendance table for absent.

Sample result for interval 20150822 to 20150829

```
    DMY    |  personId  |  onLeave
-------------------------------------
  20150823 |     1      |    0
  20150823 |     2      |    1
  20150825 |     3      |    0
  20150826 |     2      |    0
  20150827 |     8      |    0
  20150827 |     5      |    0
  20150827 |     1      |    1
  20150829 |     3      |    1
```

> Present: Entry in Attendance table with onLeave = 0
>
> Leave : Entry in Attendance table with onLeave = 1
>
> Absent: No entry in Attendance with Calendar.isHoliday = 0 on that day

I want to create a procedure that gives me the **data for all persons** within an interval according to the sample (Absent and Leave) when provided with the **@startDate** and **@endDate** parameter.

Any help, tips, clues will be deeply appreciated.

Note: I can't modify the table structure.

Comment: do you have a table with "all persons" ?

Comment: Yes! There is a table that stores all persons.

Comment: "data for all persons" but you have a parameter @personid.

Comment: Yes. But i don't want it. I want All persons data.

Comment: edited the question to make it a bit more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a list for "all persons":

the cross join between persons and calendar generates a day per person and the left join mappes the attendance, if there is no attendance the person is absent

```
SELECT p.PersonID ,
       a.*,
       absent = CASE WHEN a.onLeave IS NULL OR onLeave = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM Calendar c
CROSS JOIN Persons p 
LEFT JOIN Attendance a ON c.DMY = a.DMY AND a.PersonId = p.PersonId
WHERE C.DMY > @startDate AND C.DMY < endDate AND c.isHoliday <> 1
```